# Вывести в адаптере картинку в ListView

Tags: android

С помощью адаптера пытаюсь вывести в ListView картинки хранящиеся в assets. Названия картинок в БД в таблице в колонке image

Вот адаптер для ListView

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private int layout;

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, int flag) {
        super(context, cursor, flag);
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public RoundedImageView img;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            img = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        int _ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry._ID));
        String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IMAGE));

        holder.img = //////

    }
}
```

Тут holder.img = ////// как выводить?

Comment: Не знаю как обратиться к getAssets() в адаптере

Answer (score 1):

Согласно указаниям [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645268/how-to-load-a-image-from-assets) необходимо сделать следующее:

```
// загрузить картинку
try {
    // получить input stream
    InputStream ims = context.getAssets().open(image);
    // загрузить картинку как Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // установить картинку на ImageView
    holder.img.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    return;
}
```